# ASP.NET Core 7 Razor compilation errors in intermediate file

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I am getting compilation errors in one of my Razor pages called Print.cshtml, (In Views->Meetings folers).  The compilation errors refer to a file that does not exist, and I can't find, so I'm not sure what to do and I don't understand the errors.

The first error is:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0501  'Views_Meetings_Print.Views_Meetings_Print()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial PMBrowser   C:\Users\ProjectPath\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Views_Meetings_Print_cshtml.g.cs    270 Active
```

The folder `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators` does not exist (must be removed after compilation or is not really ever there).  The only thing I can think to do is start commenting code out of my cshtml file until I find the offending line.  Which I will do, but wondering if there is a better way.

I found that my offending line was:
@(itemCount++;)

where without the semicolon at the end it compiles just fine.  So now I know, but is there anything that makes this kind of error easier to find when it happens again?  There was no syntax error indication in the code editor (VS 2022 Community 17.6.0 Preview 1.0).

Answer (score 1):

Sourcegenerators basically generate your views for you on build by applying some weird arcane magic. If you want to get into the how and whys and where this generated code actually lands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview

To your problem: `@(itemCount++;)` is a Razor expression. More precise, an explicit Razor expression. Explicit razor expressions may contain white spaces, while implicit expression do not. Implicit would be without the paranthesis: `@itemCount++`. Razor expressions do not terminate with a semicolon.

Razor code blocks however, do terminate a statement with a semicolon. These are the ones with curly braces:

```
@{
    itemCount++;
    Debug.WriteLine("One more line to make a point");
}
```

Syntax reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#razor-syntax

Unfortunately, I can't tell you why the compiler or Visual Studio did not mark this as an error.